# Converting PyAny to a PyRef of a given type, without the extra cost of extract?

Tags: rust, pyo3

Minimal example that works but isn't quite what I want:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

use pyo3::class::basic::CompareOp;
use pyo3::class::PyObjectProtocol;
use pyo3::prelude::*;

#[pyclass]
struct MyStruct {
  foo: HashMap<i32, Vec<i32>>,
}

#[pyproto]
impl PyObjectProtocol for MyStruct {
  fn __richcmp__(&self, other: PyRef<MyStruct>, op: CompareOp) -> Py<PyAny> {
    let gil = Python::acquire_gil();
    let py = gil.python();

    if let CompareOp::Eq = op {
      let other_foo = &(other.foo);
      let res = self.foo == *other_foo;
      return res.into_py(py);
    }
    
    py.NotImplemented();
  }
}
```

So this will take a reference to a `MyStruct` living in the python heap and run the comparison on it, and my understanding is that no copying / cloning will happen.

But this isn't quite the pythonic way. The argument `other` doesn't have to be of the same type. Instead of raising a `TypeError`, the comparison method should just return `NotImplemented`.

I'm trying to change the signature so that

- I can accept arbitrary python objects. I thought `&PyAny` would be just right
- I can then check the type, or try the conversion, but *without* cloning the object from the Python heap over to Rust's heap.

Is there any way to convert, with checking of course, a `&PyAny` into a
`PyRef<MyStruct>`?

Comment: Actually it seems like the `pyproto` macro was recently fixed to return `NotImplemented` when the type conversion to the `PyRef` fails. This is awesome. But my _general_ question about best practice remains: How to accept arbitrary object from python and cast to a reference to a python class defined in Rust?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Huh, turns out the answer is quite simple. The reason I couldn't get it to work is that there were changes to PyO3.

In the past, the trait `FromPyObject` was automatically implemented for `&T` when you had a pyclass `T`.

But not so any more.

Here's the correct way:

```rust
fn do_stuff(any: &PyAny) {
  let res: PyResult<PyRef<MyStruct>> = any.extract();
  if res.is_err() { // whoops; wasn't a MyStruct after all }
}
```

Source: https://pyo3.rs/v0.13.2/migration.html

> Object extraction

> For PyClass types `T`, `&T` and `&mut T` no longer have `FromPyObject` implementations. Instead you should extract `PyRef<T>` or `PyRefMut<T>`, respectively. If `T` implements `Clone`, you can extract `T` itself. In addition, you can also extract `&PyCell<T>`, though you rarely need it.